# Writing variable to single quote in jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, syntax, single-quotes

I tried a lot but I couldn't solve this poroblem. My aim write a variable in single quote to set dynamic active but when I want to do it I get syntax errors.

```
$('#tabs a[href="#vtab" + result.step_next + ]').tab('show');
```

Comment: Try `$('#tabs a[href="#vtab' + result.step_next + '"]').tab('show');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Moving my comment to an answer</sub>

You aren't concatenating the string properly. Try:

```
$('#tabs a[href="#vtab' + result.step_next + '"]').tab('show');
```

It appears to [work here](http://jsfiddle.net/opjcqbz9/).